# jQuery UI Autocomplete not working with hashtag.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete, hashtag

In Below code I'm able create hastag that is I'm able to achieve but I want to show suggestions for hastags using autocomplete. For that I have used

```
$(this).bind( "keyup", function( event ) {
```

Can anybody suggest what is the problem with this code and how can I achieve it.

JS imported:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value="/resources/jquery/1.10.2/jquery-1.10.2.js" />"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value="/resources/jquery/1.10.2/jquery-ui.min.js" />"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value="/resources/jquery/js/jquery.autosize.js" />"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value="/resources/jquery/js/jquery.hashtags.js" />"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<c:url value="/resources/jquery/1.10.2/jquery-ui.css" />" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<c:url value="/resources/jquery/js/jquery.hashtags.css" />" type="text/css" />
```

HTML:

```
<div class="main" style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;width:1170px;">
    <textarea></textarea>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("textarea").hashtags();
    });
</script>
```

hashtags.js file:

```
(function($) {
$.fn.hashtags = function() {
    $(this).wrap('<div class="jqueryHashtags"><div class="highlighter"></div></div>').unwrap().before('<div class="highlighter"></div>').wrap('<div class="typehead"></div></div>');
    $(this).addClass("theSelector");
    $(this).autosize({append: "\n"});
    $(this).on("keyup", function() {
        var str = $(this).val();
        $(this).parent().parent().find(".highlighter").css("width",$(this).css("width"));
        str = str.replace(/\n/g, '<br>');
        if(!str.match(/(http|ftp|https):\/\/[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)+([\w.,@?^=%&amp;:\/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&amp;\/~+#-])?#([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/g) && !str.match(/(http|ftp|https):\/\/[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)+([\w.,@?^=%&amp;:\/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&amp;\/~+#-])?@([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/g) && !str.match(/(http|ftp|https):\/\/[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)+([\w.,@?^=%&amp;:\/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&amp;\/~+#-])?#([\u0600-\u06FF]+)/g) && !str.match(/(http|ftp|https):\/\/[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)+([\w.,@?^=%&amp;:\/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&amp;\/~+#-])?@([\u0600-\u06FF]+)/g)) {
                    if(!str.match(/#([\u0600-\u06FF]+)#/g)) { //arabic support
                str = str.replace(/#([\u0600-\u06FF]+)/g,'<span class="hashtag">#$1</span>');
            }else{
                str = str.replace(/#([\u0600-\u06FF]+)#([\u0600-\u06FF]+)/g,'<span class="hashtag">#$1</span>');
            }
            if(!str.match(/@([\u0600-\u06FF]+)@/g)) {
                str = str.replace(/@([\u0600-\u06FF]+)/g,'<span class="hashtag">@$1</span>');
            }else{
                str = str.replace(/@([\u0600-\u06FF]+)@([\u0600-\u06FF]+)/g,'<span class="hashtag">@$1</span>');
            }
            if(!str.match(/#([a-zA-Z0-9]+)#/g)) {
                str = str.replace(/#([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/g,'<span class="hashtag">#$1</span>');
            }else{
                str = str.replace(/#([a-zA-Z0-9]+)#([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/g,'<span class="hashtag">#$1</span>');
            }
            if(!str.match(/@([a-zA-Z0-9]+)@/g)) {
                str = str.replace(/@([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/g,'<span class="hashtag">@$1</span>');
            }else{
                str = str.replace(/@([a-zA-Z0-9]+)@([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/g,'<span class="hashtag">@$1</span>');
            }
        }
        $(this).parent().parent().find(".highlighter").html(str);
        $(this).parent().parent().find(".highlighter").autocomplete({
            minLength: 0,
            source: function(request, response) {
                alert("val1::"+$(this).parent().parent().find(".highlighter").text()); // Line where call is not coming
                $.getJSON("${pageContext. request. contextPath}/getExistingProfession",{
                                term : $(this).parent().parent().find(".highlighter").text(),
                                tagValue : $(this).parent().parent().find(".highlighter").text()
                            }, response);
            },
            focus: function() {
              return false;
            },
            select: function( event, ui ) {
              var terms = split( this.value );
              terms.pop();
              setIdProfessionInArray(ui.item.id, ui.item.value); 
              terms.push( ui.item.value );
              terms.push( "" );
              this.value = terms.join( ", " );
              return false;
            }
          });
    });

    $(this).parent().prev().on('click', function() {
        $(this).parent().find(".theSelector").focus();
    });
};
```

})(jQuery);

Comment: You should also import jQuery UI library.

Comment: Hey Artur I have tried what you said, but it didn't work :( . please check I have updated the code above.